# String interpolation in a multi-line Groovy string

Tags: groovy, string-interpolation

I have a multi-line string in which I dynamically populate an SQL query from a map. I am getting a MissingPropertyException that is a result of the query not recognising the map key or values. Is there a way around this?

```
def multiString = """
def person = ['John': 'Builder']

person.each{ key, value ->

String query = """ UPDATE person SET value = '${value}' 
                   WHERE name = '${key}' """ } 
 """
```

Comment: the code you provided works fine. could you show the statement where exception occurred and also provide stacktrace.

Comment: I forgot to add that the query itself is enclosed in a multi-line string.

Comment: now your code absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to escape the $ using a backslash.

```
def multiString = """
  def person = ['John': 'Builder']

  person.each{ key, value ->

  String query = """ UPDATE person SET value = '\${value}'
                     WHERE name = '\${value}' """ } 
"""
```