# Groovy jenkins script println doesn't work

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, artifactory

As a part of my promote artifact task I am creating a query to send to Artifactory. Unfortunately, it does not work and I am trying to debug it stepwise. Here is the message I am preparing to send. Somehow `println` returns "check", but does not show anything for `message` in the logs. Why so?

```
stage('Promote') {
  id = "0.1-2020-01-28-18-08.zip"
  try {
  message = """
    items.find(
        {
            "$and":[
                { "repo": {"$eq": "generic-dev-local"} },
                { "path": {"$match": "mh/*"} },
                { "name": {"$eq": ${id}}}
            ]
        }
    ).include("artifact.module.build.number")
    """
  println "check"
  println message
  } catch (e) {
  return [''] + e.toString().tokenize('\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String interpolation in a multi-line Groovy string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889996/string-interpolation-in-a-multi-line-groovy-string)

Comment: [String Interpolation in Groovy doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation)

Comment: @zett42 nope, that does not help. `println` still returns nothing when running in Jenkins

Comment: Have you looked into the full log for any error?

Comment: @zett42 I wish I knew how, I only have user right access to jenkins, so can't debug it there, as it complains that my code should be approved by admin (the full code has a request obj). Is there any other way to debug it?

Comment: AFAIK you should still be able to see the log (console output) of the job. Low level errors often show up in the raw log only and not in blue ocean. Within blue ocean UI you find the log on the artifacts page.

Comment: @zett42exactly, this is where I see nothing ..

Comment: Sometimes stderr doesn't pipe to the Jenkins logs. In this case, since it is in a try, I think that maybe the case. Jenkins just doesn't know what to do with that interpolated string since you need to escape all the internal quotes. Just my guess.

Comment: Yep, I removed try catch block and it started properly failing.

Comment: @Ren now try escaping all the "$" -> "\$", expect for the id variable call

Comment: @Prostagma yep, already tried and now everything works. the main problem was that it was in the try catch